# Warning message: In mean.default(filtermyData$sulfate, na.rm = TRUE) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I am writing a function to load several csv files in a single data frame.
I then filter out rows depending on particular value in column ID.

I then intend to find the mean of column sulfate/nitrate out of the filtered data frame. However I get the error as mentioned in the title.

My code is,

```
function(directory,pollutant,id=1:332)
{
    wd<-getwd()
    if(wd %in% "C:/Users/Hp/Documents/specdata")
    {}
    else
    {
        setwd(directory)
    }
    temp<-list.files(pattern="*.csv")
    myData<- lapply(temp,read.csv)
    filtermyData<-subset(myData,myData$ID %in% id)
    if(pollutant %in% "sulfate")
    {
        meanSulfate<-mean(filtermyData$sulfate,na.rm=TRUE)
        meanSulfate
    }
    else
    {
        meanNitrate<-mean(filtermyData$nitrate,na.rm=TRUE)
        meanNitrate
    }
}
```

Comment: I know Coursera hw when I see it : )

Comment: `myData` is list isn't it?

Comment: # zx8754: Yes it is a list.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with the help of other posts on stackoverflow. However I wanna know why were the column names not imported with these commands...
temp<-list.files(pattern="*.csv")
    myData<- lapply(temp,read.csv)..

I later used rbind and was able to access the column with myData$sulfate. Could anyone kindly elucidate my queury.

Comment: #plafort. i am a compelte noob in R. Yes it is indeed a question from courseera. However i am asking a queury and not the complete code. Infact as I mentioned I have resolved the code but I was flummoxed when I was not able to access the columns using $ only to realize that the columns were never imported with,
temp<-list.files(pattern="*.csv")
    myData<- lapply(temp,read.csv)

I later used rbind and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

With [ and $ the subset returns a data.frame. Try it with a vector `mean(filtermyData[['nitrate']],na.rm=T)`
It worked for me.